# Verb has been omitted in sentence

Tags: verbs

Sometimes, I've seen sentences like this:

> Copies of 14th Finance Commission report being unloaded outside the Parliament in New Delhi on Tuesday

in which VERB is not used, so, could anyone please tell that here writer is omitting VERB purposefully or is this another way to write a sentence?

Comment: This question needs a lot more context: Where does this sentence come from and is it part of a larger text? A headline? A caption? Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more context, it's impossible to give a correct answer. I see two main scenarios:

1. **Headlines, news flashes and captions**
   Due to restricted space *auxiliary* verbs (and sometimes articles) are often omitted if they are not essential to understand the text. A random sample pulled from today's Washington Post webpage: "Republicans divided as DHS shutdown looms" This is accepted standard journalistic practise. Your example reminds me of this, but without context, it's hard to say for sure.
2. **other cases**
   In most other cases this omission would be considered wrong. Of course you can easily transform one into the other by removing / inserting the appropriate auxiliary verb.

Answer (score 0):

Bad English is common in many parts of the world, including India.  The sentence should say "...are being unloaded..".

However, you are only showing a fragment of the sentence, not the whole sentence.

For example the sentence would be correct without the "are" if it read, "The copies of the 14th Finance Commission report being unloaded outside the Parliament in New Delhi on Tuesday will outline new strategies in international commerce."

Answer (score 0):

When you would like to understand a sentence, check if there is a previous sentence. Interpreting the context, It **could be** a sub clause or something.

Therefore, you need to grab all contexts to understand.